# Lualatex crashing after compiling large document

Tags: luatex, longtabu, compilation-error

I am using Lualatex because it has the property to dynamically extend its own memory. 
Currently I am using longtabu like that

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1mm}
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {|
p{30mm}|

p{20mm}|
p{20mm}|
p{30mm}|
p{20mm}|
p{35mm}|
p{15mm}|
p{15mm}|
p{15mm}|
p{30mm}|
p{30mm}|}
\hline\tableHeaderStyle
\raisebox{-0.7mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Папка \textnumero } } &
\raisebox{-4mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Пореден \\ \textnumero ~ на \\ документ } } &
\raisebox{-4mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Машинен \\ \textnumero \\ документ } } &
\raisebox{-0.7mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Документ \textnumero } } &
\raisebox{-2.3mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Дата на \\ документа } } &
\raisebox{-4mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Дата на \\ въвеждане \\ на документа } } &
\raisebox{-2.3mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Потре- \\ бител } } &
\raisebox{-2.3mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Тест\\ 1} } &
\raisebox{-2.3mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Тест\\ 2} } &
\raisebox{-2.3mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[r]{ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Стойност \\ дебит } } &
\raisebox{-2.3mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[r]{ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Стойност \\ кредит } }
\\ \hline \endhead
```

Lets add 2 lines.

```
1 & 
5000 & 
3000 & 
2 & 
25.04.2018 & 
25.04.2018 15:21:27 & 
test & 
1 & 
 & 
\multicolumn{1}{r|}{ 1 000.00 } & 
\multicolumn{1}{r|}{  }
\\ 
\tabucline[1pt on 10pt off 3pt]{1-11}
\multicolumn{11}{|p{280mm}|}{ Забележка: Latin } \\ % sum of all column widths + some extra from cell padding
\hline
```

This is going to work. Its going to work also if the last two lines repeat 1000 times.
But the document I am trying to generate its quite large. These two lines repeat between 10 000 and 20 000 times. And only then i receive this error :

```
! Missing } inserted.
```

Can anyone at least point me to a right direction ? Thank you.

**EDIT**

Here is the full code with 2 lines. I can not put 100 lines here or 10 000 times because there is limitation.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=18pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    % verbose,
    landscape,      % page orientation (landscape or portrait)
    a4paper,        % paper size
    tmargin=20mm,   % page top margin
    bmargin=20mm,   % page bottom margin
    lmargin=5mm,   % page left margin
    rmargin=5mm % page right maring
}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
%\setdefaultlanguage{bulgarian}
%\usepackage[defaultsans]{opensans} %font
%\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,bulgarian]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
%\usepackage[lutf8x]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{textcomp}

% ============================== PAGE ==============================

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\tcbd{
  \fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont
  25.04.2018 03:23:45
}}
\lhead{\tcbd{
  \fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont
  "Тест" ЕООД
}}
\rfoot{\tcbd{
  Стр. \thepage
}}
\lfoot{\tcbd{
  \fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont
  Тест
}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% ============================== TABLES ==============================

\definecolor{clTableHeaderBackground}{RGB}{192,192,192}
\definecolor{clTableHeaderText}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\newcommand{\mc}[2]{\multicolumn{ #1 }{c}{ #2 }}    % snippet for multicolumn

% Table Header Style
\newcommand{\tableHeaderStyle}{
    \rowfont{\color{clTableHeaderText}\bfseries}
    \rowcolor{clTableHeaderBackground}
}
\tabulinesep =_0.5mm^1mm     % table cell vertical padding (top and bottom)
\arrayrulewidth=0.8pt         % line width

% ============================== OTHER ==============================

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\newcommand{\resetFont}{
    \fontsize{9}{12}\selectfont
}

\newenvironment{nscenter}
 {\parskip=0pt\par\nopagebreak\centering}
 {\par\noindent\ignorespacesafterend}

%define "Twig Curly Braces Divider"
\newcommand{\tcbd}{}

%define Wrap

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\separator}{ }
 {
  \mode_if_math:TF { \allowbreak } { \- }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\wrap}{ m }
 {
  \mathers_wrap:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_mathers_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l_mathers_output_seq
\seq_new:N \l_mathers_temp_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \mathers_wrap:n #1
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_mathers_output_seq
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_mathers_input_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_mathers_input_seq
   {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_mathers_temp_seq { } { ##1 }
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l_mathers_output_seq
     { \seq_use:Nn \l_mathers_temp_seq { \allowbreak } }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_mathers_output_seq { ~ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff




\tabulinesep =_0.5mm^1mm     % table cell vertical padding (top and bottom)
\begin{document}
\fontsize{15}{13}\selectfont
\begin{nscenter}
  \textbf{Хронологичен опис на счетоводните записвания}
\end{nscenter}
\\ \vspace{-5mm}
\fontsize{12}{10}\selectfont
\begin{nscenter}
  За периода: 25.04.2018 - 25.04.2018 
\end{nscenter}
\vspace{-5mm}
\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont
\def\arraystretch{1.4}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1mm}
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {|
p{30mm}|
p{20mm}|
p{20mm}|
p{30mm}|
p{20mm}|
p{35mm}|
p{15mm}|
p{15mm}|
p{15mm}|
p{30mm}|
p{30mm}|}
\hline\tableHeaderStyle
\raisebox{-0.7mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Папка \textnumero } } &
\raisebox{-4mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Пореден \\ \textnumero ~ на \\ документ } } &
\raisebox{-4mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Машинен \\ \textnumero \\ документ } } &
\raisebox{-0.7mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Документ \textnumero } } &
\raisebox{-2.3mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Дата на \\ документа } } &
\raisebox{-4mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Дата на \\ въвеждане \\ на документа } } &
\raisebox{-2.3mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Потре- \\ бител } } &
\raisebox{-2.3mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Сметка \\ дебит } } &
\raisebox{-2.3mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Сметка \\ кредит } } &
\raisebox{-2.3mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[r]{ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Стойност \\ дебит } } &
\raisebox{-2.3mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[r]{ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Стойност \\ кредит } }
\\ \hline \endhead 
1 & 
5000 & 
3000 & 
2 & 
25.04.2018 & 
25.04.2018 15:23:45 & 
test & 
1 & 
 & 
\multicolumn{1}{r|}{ 1 000.00 } & 
\multicolumn{1}{r|}{  }
\\ 
\tabucline[1pt on 10pt off 3pt]{1-11}
\multicolumn{11}{|p{280mm}|}{ Забележка: Latin } \\ % sum of all column widths + some extra from cell padding
\hline

\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

---

---

Minimal example (Ed.)

Here is a minimal test file

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}

\usepackage{xinttools}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {|c|}
\hline\endhead 
\romannumeral\xintreplicate{9999}\\
% \\ % comment this out to trigger the problem
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

I (jfbu) tried to fiddle with the settings in texmfcnf.lua, to no effect.

**edit** actually the same issue arises with pdflatex, so Ed. has commented out the Emacs buffer variable which Ed. initially used.

But it is striking that it arises at exactly 10000 iterations and not at 9999.

Comment: I cannot reproduce with just snippets.  Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I updated the post. You just need to copy paste until you get 12000 rows. Thank you for helping !

Comment: That's not really a [**minimal** working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) but you deserve +1 for the effort.

Comment: Thank you all for participating and helping. David Carlisle gave a solution. Maybe for so long tables longtable package is the right one. I dont know why longtabu is not working since is based on longtable. The problem appears and in a simple tabular.

Comment: This looks like a memory limitation of TeX, but I can't find in texmf.cnf the suitable parameter, so I don't know if it is solvable at user level.

Comment: @jfbu no you zeroed in on it it's a tabu "feature" I'll post an answer in a bit

Comment: @jfbu pdfLatex have a memory limitation yes. Thats why I am using lualatex which dynamically extends memory. Also if you are compiling with pdflatex you can run the code with --extra-mem-bot=N.

Comment: @jfbu I added a patch so your example works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reproduce the error with a small test file by replacing the line to be repeated by

```
\testlined
```

defined by

```
\def\testline{1 & 
5000 & 
3000 & 
2 & 
25.04.2018 & 
25.04.2018 15:23:45 & 
test & 
1 & 
 & 
\multicolumn{1}{r|}{ 1 000.00 } & 
\multicolumn{1}{r|}{  }
\\ 
}

\def\testlinea{\testline\testline\testline\testline\testline\testline\testline\testline\testline\testline}%10
\def\testlineb{\testlinea\testlinea\testlinea\testlinea\testlinea\testlinea\testlinea\testlinea\testlinea\testlinea}%100
\def\testlinec{\testlineb\testlineb\testlineb\testlineb\testlineb\testlineb\testlineb\testlineb\testlineb\testlineb}%1000
\def\testlined{\testlinec\testlinec\testlinec\testlinec\testlinec\testlinec\testlinec\testlinec\testlinec\testlinec}%10000
```

The `longtable` package is designed for ling tables like this (there is a clue in the name:-) so changing it to `longtable` outputs the table.  `\rowfont` isn't defined in that case, here I just commented it out but you could get the same fonts by adding the font declarations to your p column specifiers.

This produces 358 pages of table

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=18pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    % verbose,
    landscape,      % page orientation (landscape or portrait)
    a4paper,        % paper size
    tmargin=20mm,   % page top margin
    bmargin=20mm,   % page bottom margin
    lmargin=5mm,   % page left margin
    rmargin=5mm % page right maring
}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
%\setdefaultlanguage{bulgarian}
%\usepackage[defaultsans]{opensans} %font
%\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,bulgarian]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
%\usepackage[lutf8x]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{textcomp}

% ============================== PAGE ==============================

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\tcbd{
  \fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont
  25.04.2018 03:23:45
}}
\lhead{\tcbd{
  \fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont
  "Тест" ЕООД
}}
\rfoot{\tcbd{
  Стр. \thepage
}}
\lfoot{\tcbd{
  \fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont
  Тест
}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% ============================== TABLES ==============================

\definecolor{clTableHeaderBackground}{RGB}{192,192,192}
\definecolor{clTableHeaderText}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\newcommand{\mc}[2]{\multicolumn{ #1 }{c}{ #2 }}    % snippet for multicolumn

% Table Header Style
\newcommand{\tableHeaderStyle}{
%    \rowfont{\color{clTableHeaderText}\bfseries}
%    \rowcolor{clTableHeaderBackground}
}
\tabulinesep =_0.5mm^1mm     % table cell vertical padding (top and bottom)
\arrayrulewidth=0.8pt         % line width

% ============================== OTHER ==============================

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\newcommand{\resetFont}{
    \fontsize{9}{12}\selectfont
}

\newenvironment{nscenter}
 {\parskip=0pt\par\nopagebreak\centering}
 {\par\noindent\ignorespacesafterend}

%define "Twig Curly Braces Divider"
\newcommand{\tcbd}{}

\def\testline{1 & 
5000 & 
3000 & 
2 & 
25.04.2018 & 
25.04.2018 15:23:45 & 
test & 
1 & 
 & 
\multicolumn{1}{r|}{ 1 000.00 } & 
\multicolumn{1}{r|}{  }
\\ 
}

\def\testlinea{\testline\testline\testline\testline\testline\testline\testline\testline\testline\testline}%10
\def\testlineb{\testlinea\testlinea\testlinea\testlinea\testlinea\testlinea\testlinea\testlinea\testlinea\testlinea}%100
\def\testlinec{\testlineb\testlineb\testlineb\testlineb\testlineb\testlineb\testlineb\testlineb\testlineb\testlineb}%1000
\def\testlined{\testlinec\testlinec\testlinec\testlinec\testlinec\testlinec\testlinec\testlinec\testlinec\testlinec}%10000

%define Wrap

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\separator}{ }
 {
  \mode_if_math:TF { \allowbreak } { \- }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\wrap}{ m }
 {
  \mathers_wrap:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_mathers_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l_mathers_output_seq
\seq_new:N \l_mathers_temp_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \mathers_wrap:n #1
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_mathers_output_seq
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_mathers_input_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_mathers_input_seq
   {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_mathers_temp_seq { } { ##1 }
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l_mathers_output_seq
     { \seq_use:Nn \l_mathers_temp_seq { \allowbreak } }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_mathers_output_seq { ~ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff




\tabulinesep =_0.5mm^1mm     % table cell vertical padding (top and bottom)
\begin{document}
\fontsize{15}{13}\selectfont
\begin{nscenter}
  \textbf{Хронологичен опис на счетоводните записвания}
\end{nscenter}
\\ \vspace{-5mm}
\fontsize{12}{10}\selectfont
\begin{nscenter}
  За периода: 25.04.2018 - 25.04.2018 
\end{nscenter}
\vspace{-5mm}
\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont
\def\arraystretch{1.4}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1mm}
\begin{longtable}{|
p{30mm}|
p{20mm}|
p{20mm}|
p{30mm}|
p{20mm}|
p{35mm}|
p{15mm}|
p{15mm}|
p{15mm}|
p{30mm}|
p{30mm}|}
\hline\tableHeaderStyle
\raisebox{-0.7mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Папка \textnumero } } &
\raisebox{-4mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Пореден \\ \textnumero ~ на \\ документ } } &
\raisebox{-4mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Машинен \\ \textnumero \\ документ } } &
\raisebox{-0.7mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Документ \textnumero } } &
\raisebox{-2.3mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Дата на \\ документа } } &
\raisebox{-4mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Дата на \\ въвеждане \\ на документа } } &
\raisebox{-2.3mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Потре- \\ бител } } &
\raisebox{-2.3mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Сметка \\ дебит } } &
\raisebox{-2.3mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[l]{ Сметка \\ кредит } } &
\raisebox{-2.3mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[r]{ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Стойност \\ дебит } } &
\raisebox{-2.3mm}[0mm][12mm]{ \thead[r]{ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Стойност \\ кредит } }
\\ \hline \endhead 
\testlined
\tabucline[1pt on 10pt off 3pt]{1-11}
\multicolumn{11}{|p{280mm}|}{ Забележка: Latin } \\ % sum of all column widths + some extra from cell padding
\hline

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

---

jfbu narrowed down the problem. `longtabu` actually disables `longtables` support for long tables, so that it can hold the entire table in memory to handle `X` columns, it gets away with it as machines are bigger than they were in 1990 and so the longtable chunksize is set at 10000 rather than longtables default of 20. here I make it \maxdimen (the largest integer TeX can hold)

using the smaller example that jfbu added

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\longtabu {\tabu@longtrue
   \ifmmode\PackageError{tabu}{longtabu not allowed in math mode}\fi
   \def\tabu@{\longtable}\def\endlongtabu{\endlongtable}%
   \LTchunksize=\maxdimen
   \expandafter\let\csname tabu*\endcsname \tabu
   \expandafter\def\csname endlongtabu*\endcsname{\endlongtabu}%
   \let\LT@startpbox \tabu@LT@startpbox % \everypar{ array struts }
   \tabu@spreadfalse \tabu@negcoeffalse \tabu@settarget
}% {longtabu}
\makeatother
\def\x{\\\hline}

\usepackage{xinttools}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter\errorcontextlines\maxdimen
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {|c|}
\hline\endhead 
\romannumeral\xintreplicate{9999}\x
\x % comment this out to trigger the problem
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to solve the problem. This is a copy from the longtabu documentation "An environment longtabu – based on D. Carlisle longtable package".
I was thinking that is designed to do the same as longtabu as you said "there is a clue in the name".

Comment: @LubomirBorisov an omelette is based on an egg but don't try to hatch chicks from one:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oh well, I recalled this chunksize business dimly and made a search for `10000` in tabu manual but that should have been `10 000`... then I was a bit exhausted from having cut down the minimal example to a minimal example `;-)`

Comment: manual says ``Presently, longtabu with X columns works only if \LTchunksize is greater than the number of rows.`` Your patch seems to suggest that there is no user interface to modify the `10000` ? well yes of course `\LTchunksize=\@M` is hard-coded. Thus the "feature" of tabu is only not to have provided a means to modify this at user level.

Comment: @jfbu it didn't occur to me to look at the manual:-)